# How to submit ajax form on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I want my page to send ajax on page load, but as I'm really new, I tried to use someone's else code.

I wanted you to help me know why it's not working. **Note:** I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'ajaxSubmit'`

Here's the code:

```
{% if my_data %}
  <form id="data-form-1" action="/dta/import/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="current_data" value="{{ my_data }}" />
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

And here's the script:

```
<script>document.getElementById('data-form-1').ajaxSubmit({
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response, statusText, xhr){
          if(response.result.toLowerCase() == 'ok')
          {
            $(".list-empty").remove();
            addDataArray(response.data);
            btnStatus('success');
          }
          else
            btnStatus('error');
        },
        error : function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
          btnStatus('error');
        }
      });
</script>
```

Hope you can help me.

**Note 2:** I don't use PHP, just js and HTML

Comment: Seems like .ajaxSubmit is part of a javascript plugin / library / file that is not loaded

Comment: Do you use jquery or pure js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ajaxSubmit` function is jQuery, not a regular JavaScript function on a form, so you need a jQuery object. Change

```
document.getElementById('data-form-1').ajaxSubmit(...
```

to

```
$('#data-form-1').ajaxSubmit(...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it sends the request

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('data-form-1')` is not a Jquery object. `ajaxSubmit` can be invoked only on converting the same into a jquery object using `$('#data-form-1')`